# how install libgstreamer0.10-plugins-bad on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, gstreamer

I can't find two gstreamer package on repository:

- libgstreamer0.10-plugins-bad
- libgstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly

How can install it on Ubuntu 16.04 64bit?
Is it safe to install 15.10 deb version?

Answer (score 3):

You could install `ubuntu-restricted-extras` package:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Comment: This worked for me, but I felt like it was an overkill / shotgun approach.  It seemed that a ton of additional stuff got installed, which I had no idea what it was.  I was happy my problem was resolved though!